# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Post"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have been following the tutorial on MEAN stack (https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/) and have stumbled on a problem. When trying to do `npm start`, I am getting an error message, specifically the following:

```
C:\Linked\linked>npm start

> linked@0.0.0 start C:\Linked\linked
> node ./bin/www


C:\Linked\linked\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:329
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
            ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Post".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (C:\Linked\linked\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:329:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Linked\linked\routes\index.js:2:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Linked\linked\app.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Linked\linked\bin\www:7:11)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! linked@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the linked@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the linked package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls linked
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Linked\linked\npm-debug.log
```

The following are the files that likely contain the problem. I tried tinkering around different lines, mainly in `routes\index.ejs`, but I have not been able to fix this problem yet.

**routes\index.ejs**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;

// GET posts
router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(posts);
  });
});

// POST a post
router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);

  post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});

...
```

**models\Posts.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

// Upvote method
PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};
```

**public\javascripts\angularApp.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');
var app = angular.module('linked', ['ui.router']);
```

Please let me know if I anything is unclear.

Comment: requiring mongoose on client !?

Comment: As I stated earlier, I am following a tutorial, so I am new to this stack. Where else would require mongoose?!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are not including the models files in your index.ejs files - you are just referencing model references within mongoose.

Where you have

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
```

Replace these with require statements that link to your models/Posts.js file

```
var Post = require('models/Posts');
```